# Organstrafverfügung in Österreich

Tags: austrian

In meinen uralten Unterlagen habe ich einen Österreichischen Strafzettel von 1990 gefunden. Der ist betitelt mit dem schönen Wort

> Organstrafverfügung

Ich weiß nicht, ob der Begriff auch heute noch verwendet wird, habe allerdings auch Begrifflichkeiten gefunden, die (in Deutschland) als

> Organverfügung

gefunden werden können - was natürlich was ganz anderes heißt, es geht nämlich um eine Organspende -

Ich weiß noch, dass ich damals keine Niere spenden musste, um den Strafzettel zu bezahlen ;).

- Wird der Begriff heute noch verwendet?
- Warum heißt (hieß?) das so?

Comment: Wenn ich Wikipedia richtig verstehe, wird das [heute noch genutzt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organstrafverf%C3%BCgung). Die [Herkunft] ist das [Organ der öffentlichen Aufsicht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organ_der_%C3%B6ffentlichen_Aufsicht), also ein "staatlich bestelltes Organ mit der Aufsicht über die Einhaltung der öffentlich-rechtlichen Regelungen (Gesetze, Verordnungen udgl.)".

Comment: @IQV - korrekt, mach' doch eine Antwort aus dem Kommentar. Der Begriff Organstrafverfügung oder Organmandat ist tatsächlich spezifisch österreichisch; das "Organ-" deutet darauf hin, dass hier eine Strafe nicht durch die Justiz, sondern durch die Exekutive verhängt wird (das deutsche Pendant ist die Ordnungswidrigkeit, die gleichfalls von Verwaltungsbehörden geahndet wird). Den Begriff "Organverfügung" hingegen gibt es tatsächlich auch im Deutschen - er bezeichnet hier einen Spezialfall der Patientenverfügung, der die Organspende betrifft.

Comment: @tohuwawohu Ich "weiß" aber nicht, ob der Begriff heute noch verwendet wird. Ich vermute es nur, weil der Wikipedia-Artikel sich so liest, als ob das immer noch der Fall ist. Und eine Vermutung wollte ich nicht als Antwort schreiben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ja, der Begriff Organstrafverfügung wird in Österreich auch heute noch benutzt (siehe [§ 50 Verwaltungsstrafgesetz](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/Dokument.wxe?Abfrage=Bundesnormen&Dokumentnummer=NOR40147731&ResultFunctionToken=0639def7-65c1-4f0b-803d-cd0dfab8b041&Position=1&Kundmachungsorgan=&Index=&Titel=vstg&Gesetzesnummer=&VonArtikel=&BisArtikel=&VonParagraf=50&BisParagraf=&VonAnlage=&BisAnlage=&Typ=&Kundmachungsnummer=&Unterzeichnungsdatum=&FassungVom=20.01.2017&VonInkrafttretedatum=&BisInkrafttretedatum=&VonAusserkrafttretedatum=&BisAusserkrafttretedatum=&NormabschnittnummerKombination=Und&ImRisSeit=Undefined&ResultPageSize=100&Suchworte=)). Er kommt daher, dass es keine Strafverfügung der Behörde ist, sondern "das Aufsichtsorgan" (also der Polizist etc. im Einsatz vor Ort) von sich aus tätig wird. Es gibt im Normalfall kein weiteres Ermittlungsverfahren, keine Möglichkeit zur Stellungnahme, kein Rechtsmittel -- ein extrem abgekürztes Verfahren also. Bei Nichtbezahlung wird dann das sog. "ordentliche Verfahren" eingeleitet.

Answer (score 3):

Ja, das hieß bei uns in Österreich immer schon so (jedenfalls seit ich auf der Welt bin), und heißt auch heute noch so.

### das Organ

Ein Organ ist entweder ein Beamter der Polizei, oder ein speziell ausgebildeter Mitarbeiter der Straßenaufsicht, der jedoch von der zuständigen Verwaltungsstrafbehörde (Landespolizeidirektion ode  Bezirksverwaltungsbehörde) eine besondere Ermächtigung erhält.

Organe dürfen, wenn sie dienstlich eine Verwaltungsübertretung feststellen, sofort die Bestrafung des Täters einleiten, ohne dass dafür ein Gericht eingeschaltet werden muss. Voraussetzung ist allerdings, dass die Strafe, die für die Verwaltungsübertretung angedroht wird, 90 Euro nicht übersteigt.

### das Organmandat

Das ist nichts weiter als ein Synonym für ...

### die Organstrafverfügung

Das ist eine Strafverfügung, die von einem Organ (also von keinem Gericht) ausgestellt wird. Die Verfügung wird schriftlich ausgestellt, dieses Dokument wird »Strafzettel« genannt. Eine solche Verfügung ist sofort wirksam, und es kann dagegen kein Einspruch erhoben werden. Allerdings kann man manchmal mit dem Organ freundlich reden und den Sachverhalt aufklären, dann kann das Organ eine bereits ausgestellte Verfügung auch zurücknehmen (den Strafzettel zerreißen). Das liegt im Ermessen des Organs.

Der Täter hat zwei Wochen Zeit, um die Geldstrafe zu bezahlen. Tut er das nicht, wird automatisch eine Anzeige bei der Verwaltungsbehörde gemacht und dadurch das ordentliche Verfahren eingeleitet. Im ordentlichen Verfahren beurteilt die Verwaltungsbehörde den Sachverhalt und verhängt im Normalfall eine deutlich höhere Strafe. Allerdings hat der Beklagte jetzt die Möglichkeit, gegen den ordentlichen Strafbescheid Einspruch zu erheben.

Das Haupteinsatzgebiet dieses verkürzten Verwaltungsverfahrens ist das Bestrafen von Falschparkern. Hier wird das Dokument, auf dem die Organstrafverfügung niedergeschrieben ist (der Strafzettel) hinter die Windschutzscheibe des Fahrzeuges geklemmt. Ein anders Einsatzgebiet ist die Bestrafung von Fahrern, die während der Fahr ein Handy benutzen und von der Polizei angehalten werden.

Theoretisch können Organe auch andere Verwaltungsübertretungen bestrafen, sofern sie mit maximal 90 Euro Strafe bedroht sind, in der Praxis werden aber nur kleinere Verkehrsdelikte auf diese Weise bestraft.

---

**Anmerkung**

Dafür muss man in Österreich niemals für irgend etwas Bußgeld bezahlen. Es gibt in Österreich nämlich kein Bußgeld. Ich vermute, dass die Verhängung von Bußgeldern in Deutschland ähnlich abläuft wie das Ausstellen von Organmandaten in Österreich. (Wie gesagt: Reine Vermutung, denn ich habe von deutschem Recht kaum eine Ahnung).

Verwandt mit der Organstrafverfügung sind die Anonymverfügung und die Strafverfügung. Diese verkürzten Verfahren sind hier recht verständlich erklärt: https://www.help.gv.at/Portal.Node/hlpd/public/content/102/Seite.1020110.html

Comment: Vor dem Verwaltungsgericht kommt aber noch das ordentliche Verfahren der ersten Instanz ... Gegen dieses Straferkenntnis, das ist richtig, ist dann Berufung beim Landesverwaltungsgericht und in weiterer Folge uU beim Verwaltungsgerichtshof möglich.

Comment: Der Ausdruck »Verwaltungsgericht« ist mehrdeutig. Im weiteren Sinn ist jedes Gericht, das eine Verwaltungsgerichtsbarkeit ausübt, ein Verwaltungsgericht. In diesem Sinn waren meine Ausführungen gemeint. In der Zählung der Instanzen wäre das so etwas wie die nullte Instanz. In engeren Sinn hast du aber natürlich recht, denn Verwaltungsgerichte im engeren Sinn sind nur die »Verwaltungsgerichte erster Instanz« also die Landesverwaltungsgerichte, das Bundesverwaltungsgericht und das Bundesfinanzgericht. Der Verwaltungsgerichtshof ist die zweite (und letzte) Instanz.

Comment: Es geht mir darum, dass ein Zugang zu (Verwaltungs-) **Gerichtsbarkeit** erst mit der Berufung möglich ist. Davor entscheidet in jedem Fall eine Behörde, für die Grundsätze der Gerichtsbarkeit (Unabhängigkeit, usw.) gerade nicht gelten. Die Verwaltungsbehörden erster Instanz (BHs & Co.) sind monokratisch organisierte Behörden und gerade keine Gerichte ... das alles führt hier aber ein bisschen weit :-)

Comment: ich hab's eh im Text geändert.

Answer (score 2):

[Organstrafverfügung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organstrafverf%C3%BCgung)

> Eine Organstrafverfügung (umgangssprachlich auch „Organmandat“, „Strafmandat“ oder „Strafzettel“, im Polizeijargon „Orgerl“ genannt) ist eine in Österreich mittels spezieller Formulare erstellte Verfügung. Diese wird von den ermächtigten Organen der öffentlichen Aufsicht, wegen bestimmter von ihnen dienstlich wahrgenommener Verwaltungsübertretungen ausgestellt, um eine Geldstrafe einzuheben.